# Slurm: get limits for account

Tags: linux, hpc, slurm

Our cluster is using SLURM to manage our job queue. Slurm is monitoring how many core hours each account has used, and will down-prioritize jobs submitted from an account that has used more than the allotted core hours.

Is there a command in slurm that will show me these limits for my account? I would like to know the number of core hours i can use before being down-prioritized.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the number in SLURMs grant files. Mine were located in /usr/share/slurm/calc-cluster/grantfile

Each row is an slurm account, and the core hour limit is the second field from the left, separated by :